# Lightning Web Component fails when added to Utility Bar

Tags: lightning-web-components, utility-bar

When trying to add my LWC in the utlity bar, it fails with this message "There was an error saving the page: PropertyType cannot be specified for flexipages of type UTILITY_BAR."

This is me metadata:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__UtilityBar</target>
 </targets>
 <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__UtilityBar">
         <property name="prop1" type="Boolean"/>
    </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I tried to add lightning component to Utility Bar. In my case Utility Bar also had "Object-Linking Notification" item. When I removed it I was able to add my LWC to the Utility Bar. After that I added "Object-Linking Notification" item again without any error. I don't know what it is, it looks like a bug in Salesforce.